# Multiprocessing chunks of a python list of sentences

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pytorch, pool

I'm trying to do some operations on a list of sentences using python `Pool()` to use all cores but it keeps running for a long time without any response.

here is the code structure I'm using :

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
from flair.embeddings import WordEmbeddings
from flair.data import Sentence



def procces_sents(chunks):

    sentences = [Sentence(i) for i in chunks]
    # embed a sentence using glove.
    glove_embedding.embed(sentence)

    for sent in sentences:
        for token in sent:
            if token in my_dict:
                pass
            else:
                pass


# init embedding
glove_embedding = WordEmbeddings('glove')


my_dict={}
my_list["1.txt"]
n=32
filepath = "/some/path/"
for filename in my_list:
    with open(os.path.join(filepath,filename) ,"r") as m:

    all=[]
    data = m.readlines()
    all = [x.strip() for x in all_data]

    all_chunks = [all[i * n:(i + 1) * n] for i in range((len(all) + n - 1) // n )]


    p=Pool()
    p.map(procces_sents, all_chunks)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

I expect that each core takes a 32 sized chunk of sentences and process them.

`all` is a list of all sentences

`all_chunks` is chunks of `all` list (each containing 32 sentences)
P.S. I'm using flair framework (https://github.com/zalandoresearch/flair)
Does anybody know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: the code has a lot of syntax and formatting errors - that's what's wrong with the code you posted at least.

Comment: it would be easier to help if you include your `clean_it` code or at least describe how it works, so we may estimate its performance. At a glance, it seems that most of the time is spent on data reading/preprocessing, which you perform in the main process, before passing to child processes